# Android Clear Middle Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, stack

I have 5 Activities,

A - Base Activity

B,C,D - Normal Activities

E - Final Activity

A-B-C-D-E

I navigate from A to B to C to D, D takes me to E. I want behaviour : if I press back button on D it should take me to C , back button from C should take me to B down to A. But if I have moved to Activity E from D, I want the back button from E it should take me to A skipping B,C and D.

Comment: did you try overriding the [onBackPressed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) in the Activity E to navigate you to A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `E`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will go back to `A`, finishing `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.

Using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will ensure that you return to the existing instance of `A`. If you want to also finish the existing instance of `A` and create a new one to return to, simply remove `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable to track which activity you're coming from. Then override onBackPressed to check that variable and move to the appropriate activity. Something like:

```
public static Boolean skipActivities = false;
```

Then when you start activity E from D set it to true. For your activity E:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (skipActivities){
        //start activity A, skipActivities should be reset to false also
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `static` variable for this is the wrong approach. This is bad architecture. There are simple `Intent` flags that do exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

you can "group" you activities, by using `affinity`. 
So in Manifest file add `android:taskAffinity="activity.normal"` to activities B,C,D,E. And now you'll be able to finish all this group in any of this activities by calling `finishAffinity()` (instead of usual `finish()`) in your case you can just add to E activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Horrible answer. Using `taskAffinity` for this purpose is completely wrong. Not only that but this feature exists only on API level 16 and higher. If you provide different `taskAffinity` on different activities in the manifest, you will quickly end up with 2 tasks for your application, which is certainly not what you want, nor what the user expects. Doing this opens a large can of worms that you need to completely understand before doing it. There are simple `Intent` flags to do exactly what OP wants, and it works on API level 1 and higher.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about such flag!